# How to do a READme style markup in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty new to reactjs. I was assigned with a task which consists of generating the "privacy policy" of the website. The layout of the page kinda looks like a readme of github.

```
1.header
 ***some points in block letters***
 A. subsection
 B. another subsection
   - item
   - item
 C. a)item
    b)item
```

I could easily do with simple header and paragraph tags with some styling. But we've included translations in the page, so all of the texts are coming from a json file incorporated with `export default defineMessages()` from messages.js.
Is there any way there is some kind of markup or template which will make my work easier?

n.b. Being a novice to reactjs, I tried my best to make the question as much simple as I could. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you use an external dependency like https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown or something like that ?

Comment: I really cannot use any external dependency for the project :|

Comment: Or either include some kind of bundled library in one file (https://github.com/probablyup/markdown-to-jsx) or make your own parser -> ast -> renderer, I think ...